# how do I do a symbolic LU decomposition on a 6x6 matrix with parameters?

Tags: matrix, wolframalpha

hello i need to find the decomposition of this matrix

[Matrix](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LU+decomposition+of+%7B%7B2x%2C-x%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2Fl%7D%2C%7B-x%2C2x%2C-2x%2C0%2C0%2C1%2Fl%7D%2C%7B-x%2Cx%2C0%2C-2x%2Cx%2C1%2Fl%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C0%2C-x%2C4x%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D)

but as you can see wolfram dose not solve it.
it is strange because for example it can solve this one:

[Matrix solvable](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LU+decomposition+of+%7B%7B-4%2C-1%2C0%2C-1%2Fx%7D%2C%7B-1%2C-2%2C%2B2%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C0%2C0%7D%7D)

which contains parameters as the same above.

How can i make the decomposition of that matrix with any kind of software ?

I can solve this using Scilab Programming language? (which is open source) or R or Octave or things equivalent...

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it can be done with MuPad, but it is not free.

[image: MuPad]

My guess is that this matrix is too big for the free version of W/Alpha.

It can also be done with [wxMaxima](http://andrejv.github.com/wxmaxima/) and it is free.

[image: wxMaxima]

Comment: thank you very much there is anything like this but free ? thank you ja72 :)

Comment: I would recommend trying out Maxima, or the GUI front end wxMaxima, http://andrejv.github.com/wxmaxima

Comment: please can you put +1 to my question ? admins says it is not useful for the comunity

Comment: Maybe re-phrase the question like, "how do I do a symbolic LU decomposition on a 6x6 matrix?"